# tabularray and itemize compatibility

Tags: itemize, tabularray

Is `tabularray` package incompatible with `itemize` environment? Simple MWE is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{%
colspec={Xl}, hlines, vlines
}
text & text\\
\begin{itemize}
    \item text 1
    \item text 2
\end{itemize} & text 3 \\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

I get many errors like "Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. \end", but the output is produced somehow. Could this be fixed?

Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I can offer a workaround:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray,varwidth,enumitem}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tblr}{
  colspec={Xl}, hlines, vlines
}
text & text\\
\begin{varwidth}[t]{\linewidth}
\begin{itemize}[topsep=0pt,parsep=0pt]
    \item abc def abc def abc def abc def
          abc def abc def abc def abc def
          abc def abc def abc def abc def
    \item abc def abc def abc def abc def
          abc def abc def abc def abc def
          abc def abc def abc def abc def\strut
\end{itemize}
\end{varwidth} & text 3 \\
abc def abc def abc def abc def
abc def abc def abc def abc def
abc def abc def abc def abc def
 & xyz
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This solution justifies the text inside the enumerate rather, while @L.J.R.'s solution flushes it left.

Comment: @ChristophThiede Add `\raggedright` at the appropriate spot.

Answer (score 10):

From https://github.com/lvjr/tabularray/issues/36

I have added `varwidth` library and `measure` option to `tabularray` package. You can put vertical material inside cells with `\UseTblrLibrary{varwidth}` and option `measure=vbox`. You can also set `measure=vbox` as default option.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{varwidth}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{
  colspec = {Xl}, hlines, vlines,
  measure = vbox,
}
  text & text \\
  \begin{itemize}
    \item text 1
    \item text 2
  \end{itemize} & text 3 \\
\end{tblr}

% set "measure=vbox" as default
\SetTblrInner{measure=vbox}

\begin{tblr}{
  colspec = {Xl}, hlines, vlines,
}
  text & text \\
  \begin{itemize}
    \item text 1
    \item text 2
  \end{itemize} & text 3 \\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You may download the latest package file from
https://github.com/lvjr/tabularray/raw/main/tabularray.sty
or wait for version `2021N` scheduled on September 1st. I need to update the manual before next release.

But it is better to use @egreg's solution, because there is extra vertical space around itemized cells (the same is true for `tabular` and `tabularx` environments).

Comment: thank you! I checked new version, works almost perfect :). Almost, because if I add another string of text (make multi-row) in that cell via `{\begin{itemize} ... \end{itemize} \\ Next string of text}` it gives errors, but egreg's solution works in this case.

Comment: Like a normal document, you don't need \\ after `\end{itemize}`. Just remove it.

Comment: ah I see, thanks.

Comment: To avoid this vertical space, I discovered this workaround: use package `enumitem`, then `\vspace*{-\baselineskip}` right before the `itemize` environment, the last with the option `\begin{itemize}[nosep]`.

Answer (score 6):

Enclose the `itemize` environment within a `minipage` of width `\hsize`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tblr}{%
colspec={Xl}, hlines, vlines
}
text & text\\
\begin{minipage}{\hsize}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item text 1
    \item text 2
  \end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
& text 3 \\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Didn't work for me, caused issues with vertical alignment in the other rows. The other offered solution worked (using `\varwidth`)

Answer (score 3):

This is the recommended solution for using `itemize` inside `tabularray` from the [official documentation](https://markov.htwsaar.de/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tabularray/tabularray.pdf):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{varwidth}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tblr}{
  colspec={Xl}, measure=vbox, hlines, vlines, stretch=-1
}
text & text\\
\begin{itemize}[nosep]
    \item abc def abc def abc def abc def
          abc def abc def abc def abc def
          abc def abc def abc def abc def
    \item abc def abc def abc def abc def
          abc def abc def abc def abc def
          abc def abc def abc def abc def
\end{itemize} & text 3 \\
abc def abc def abc def abc def
abc def abc def abc def abc def
abc def abc def abc def abc def
 & xyz
\end{tblr}
```

[image]

In particular, note that the `stretch=-1` option avoids vertical space above and below the list.

If you also want to avoid horizontal space before the list like me, set `\setlength{\leftmargini}{.25cm}` anywhere before the `itemize`.